# System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute must be in same project as controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a System.Web.Http.ApiController-derived controller:

```
[LoggingFilterApi]
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
     public IHttpActionResult Ads();
}
```

with the filter defined as follows:

```
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace pecom.Common.Filters
{
    public class LoggingFilterApiAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext ctx)
        {
            var msg = ctx.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.Name + "." + ctx.ActionDescriptor.ActionName +
                "(" + ctx.Request.RequestUri.ToString();

            ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(ctx.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType);
            logger.Info(msg);
            base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
        }
    }
}
```

When `LoggingFilterApiAttribute.cs` is part of the controller's `.csproj`, `OnActionExecuting` is called as expected.  However, if `LoggingFilterApiAttribute.cs` is moved to a different `.csproj` (to facilitate code reuse), `OnActionExecuting` is *not* called as expected.  Weird.

Anyone seen this?  For the time being I'm duplicating filters across our projects, which is somewhat suboptimal.  This is with ASP.NET MVC 5.2.

Cheers, Pete

Comment: It is called, it just doesn't log. How do you initialize Log4Net?

Comment: @CodeCaster from using breakpoints I can tell you it is not called (when LoggingFilterApiAttribute.cs is in a different proj). And as an aside, filters deriving from System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute do not exhibit this weird behaviour.

Comment: I'm seeing this too. I set up a basic Web API project, created a filter in it that does nothing but write to Trace in both OnExecuting and OnExecuted, added it to the global filter collection, ran it and it worked fine. Moved the filter to a separate assembly, added appropriate references and wired things back up, and it no longer runs.

Comment: I've just thrown together a test API project and a class library and this works fine using the code in the OP. MVC 5.2 .Net 4.5  I've used Filters in different projects many many times, there's no reason it shouldn't work. Are you using IIS Express or IIS? Is the API project and the class library set to the same framework version?

Comment: System.Web.Mvc v5.2.2.0. Both projects are .NET Framework 4.5. I have tried in IIS Express via F5-debug (seeing behavior in debugger and in the VS output window from Trace.Debug) and also in local IIS and observing trace output via dbgview. I have tried by adding the filter to the global filters as well as just adding it to an API method via an attribute. The result is always the same: If I use a filter that's defined in the web project, it runs, but f I use the same implementation defined in a separate library, it does not. There are no exceptions, warnings etc. anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried creating 2 new test projects (web & library) completely separate to this with just the bare minimum in to see if you can run the filter in a different project then? Stripping things back is one way I find solutions to problems

Comment: Yes, see the comment above. I created an out-of-the-box, unmodified Web API project with no authentication and a class library. A filter in the Web API project will get called, but one in the class library will not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most likely have a mismatch in Web Api 2 versions. No matter which version of MVC, your controller is a Web Api one, so you have to pay attention to Web Api related assemblies.

I'm pretty sure that, if you check the version of `System.Web.Http` in both your MVC project and your class library, they'll be different, and therefore the discovery mechanism is not able to find your custom filter. Just fix the problem by making them match and it should work.

One simple way to fix that is to reference the latest Web Api 2 package (`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core`) in your class library, *and* to upgrade the same package in your MVC project to make them match (or by messing with assembly redirects if you like so). If, for example, you just copied the code into the class library and then used something like Resharper to resolve the references, it might most likely have picked version 4.x of `System.Web.Http` from GAC, instead of version 5.x that you need here.

I tried what you did and it reproduced your same issue, and this procedure solved it.

Comment: Great find, this was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work in a few steps :

1. Create an MVC application
2. Create an empty class library
3. add the MVC framework to the class library using nuget
4. add reference to System.Web to the class Library project
5. Copy your code in a new class of the class library
6. Remove code related the logger for testing purpose
7. Replace HttpActionContext ctx by ActionExecutingContext
   filterContext
8. Replace ctx.Request.RequestUri.ToString() by
   filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url
9. Reference the Class library project
10. Add the the filter to the home controller

Job done